# Paypal Adaptive Payments mobile app hangs on completion or cancel

Tags: ruby, mobile, paypal, payment

I have a Ruby On Rails mobile app that uses PayPal Adaptive Payments with a minibrowser. The app works fine when running in Safari on an iPhone: after completing the payment (or canceling out if it), the *returnFromPaypal* callback function is executed and the user is redirected to a reservation page. 
 
However, when I run the app in full-screen mode (from an icon saved to the home screen, which is the intended mode of operation), the app hangs on a PayPal page when I either cancel the payment or complete it, with the messages "Just a moment - this window will close automatically" and "Returning" respectively.
Below is the .haml view of my payment page (sorry I don't have an HTML version).
Anyone has any idea what is going on? Thank you!

```
= javascript_include_tag  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/apdg.js"
#edit_payment.current
  .scroll
    %ul
      %li
        = form_tag "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay", :method=>'get', :target=>"PPDGFrame", :class=>"standard" do
          = hidden_field_tag :type, "mini", :name=>"expType"
          = hidden_field_tag :paykey, @pay_key, :name=>"paykey"
          = image_submit_tag "paypal_button.jpg", :id=>"submitBtn", :class=>"submit"
    :javascript
      var returnFromPayPal = function(){
          window.location.href = get_full_url("#{room_reservation_path(@room,@reservation)}");
      };                                                                                                                                  
      var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({trigger: 'submitBtn',expType: 'mini', callbackFunction: 'returnFromPayPal'});
```

[screenshot complete http://ec2-23-21-163-203.compute-1.amazonaws.com/images/scrn_complete.png](http://ec2-23-21-163-203.compute-1.amazonaws.com/images/scrn_complete.png)
[screenshot canceled http://ec2-23-21-163-203.compute-1.amazonaws.com/images/scrn_canceled.png](http://ec2-23-21-163-203.compute-1.amazonaws.com/images/scrn_canceled.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is "work as designed" as I understand. Just catch redirects like https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/closewindow?execution=e7s1 in your WebView and call payment check method on your server.

In ***apdg.js*** you can find the check:

```
if (ua.match(/iPhone|iPod|Android|Blackberry.*WebKit/i)) {
    win = window.open('', this.name);
    winOpened = true;
}
```

So your current window is completely replaced. No chance for callback.

Or you can support **multiple windows** in WebView itself.
For example Android:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("web browser");
```

and
@Override

```
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg) {
```

Not sure about multiple windows in iOS WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue until I changed my code to redirect to PayPal in a new window.  Then when the user completes the payment or cancels, the page doesn't hang, it automatically closes.

More information regarding the mini browser experience (expType=mini) can be found here:

[Adaptive Payments without modal box or popups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283272/adaptive-payments-without-modal-box-or-popups/17729106)